# Problem receiving inputs in pyqt5 and performing learning machine operations on it

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pyqt5, random-forest

I want to take all the inputs of this and when I press the button, it will use these inputs for me as input for random forest operations, but when I press the button, the program will be interrupted.

for do this I use pyqt5 and sk-learn RandomForest

I want to get the inputs floating and use it to predict the machine learning system trained in the random forest method and display the result of my system forecast on the screen and the text that fits the forecast below. Show it but I do not know pyqt5
Help us if possible

Please see the image:
**[my pyqt5 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omQJi.png)**

```
import pandas as pa
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pa.read_csv("data.csv")
y = data['Score']
x = data.drop(["name", "Score"], axis=1)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20)

Forest = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor()
RandomForest = Forest.fit(x_train, y_train)
# print(RandomForest.score(x_train, y_train))

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Heidari(QWidget):

 def setupUi(self, Heidari):
    Heidari.setObjectName("Heidari")
    Heidari.resize(500, 500)
    Heidari.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 500))
    Heidari.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 500))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("B Nazanin")
    font.setPointSize(12)
    Heidari.setFont(font)
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../Downloads/artificial-intelligence.png"), 
    QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    Heidari.setWindowIcon(icon)
    Heidari.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
    Heidari.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.Persian, QtCore.QLocale.Iran))
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Heidari)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
    self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 501, 501))
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 127))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 191))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 127, 63))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(170, 170, 84))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 127))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 191))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 127))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 191))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 127, 63))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(170, 170, 84))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 127))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 191))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 127, 63))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 127))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 191))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 127, 63))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(170, 170, 84))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 127, 63))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(127, 127, 63))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 127))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 127))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 127))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    self.frame.setPalette(palette)
    self.frame.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
    self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
    self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.frame)
    self.splitter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 420, 291, 41))
    self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.store)
    self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.frame)
    self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 130, 421, 121))
    self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
    self.splitter_3 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.frame)
    self.splitter_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 280, 167, 108))
    self.splitter_3.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
    self.splitter_3.setObjectName("splitter_3")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_3)
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.input1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_3)
    self.input1.setObjectName("input1")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_3)
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.input2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_3)
    self.input2.setObjectName("input2")
    self.splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.frame)
    self.splitter_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 280, 167, 108))
    self.splitter_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
    self.splitter_2.setObjectName("splitter_2")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_2)
    self.label.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.input3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_2)
    self.input3.setObjectName("input3")
    self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_2)
    self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
    self.input4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_2)
    self.input4.setObjectName("input4")
    self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.frame)
    self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 421, 81))
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    self.lcdNumber.setPalette(palette)
    self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
    Heidari.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    self.retranslateUi(Heidari)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Heidari)

def retranslateUi(self, Heidari):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Heidari.setWindowTitle(_translate("Heidari", "Fateme Heidari and Fateme Hatami"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Heidari", "محاسبه نمره من"))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("Heidari", "معدل"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("Heidari", "نمره تست "))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Heidari", "نمره آخرین امتحان ریاضی"))
    self.label_4.setText(_translate("Heidari", "ساعات مطالعه در طول روز"))

 def store(self):
    x1 = float(self.input1)
    x2 = float(self.input2)
    x3 = float(self.input3)
    x4 = float(self.input4)
    z = RandomForest.predict([[x1, x2, x3, x4]])
    print(z)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys

  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  Heidari = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
  ui = Ui_Heidari()
  ui.setupUi(Heidari)
  Heidari.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `self.input1` is a widget (as the other 3), you cannot make it a float, you want *its text*. Change to `x1 = float(self.input1.text())`. Also: 1. You shall not edit pyuic files, read how to properly [use Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)); 2. consider QDoubleSpinBox instead of QLineEdit; 3. don't use fixed geometries, but [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html); 4. when your program crashes, run it in a terminal/prompt to read its error traceback; 5. always try to provide a [mre] (almost 90% of your code was completely useless for the question);

Comment: please help me how to write this code

Comment: I've already told you what you need to do. Sorry, but this is not a tutorial website, these are extremely basic programming topics.